# Wifi country greyed out on fresh buster install

Tags: wifi

I just have done a fresh install of Raspbian Buster on a 3b+ on my home network. The box has been working fine for years running wheezy. The box isn't connected by ethernet.

Trying to set up Localisation prefs and the `Wifi Country` is greyed out and the Network icon on the top-right of desktop says no interfaces found.

Have tried setting the country name in `raspi-config` options but get an error saying `N2 error`.

Have tried:

```
nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and edited to read:

```
   country=GB
_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="<network_ssid>"
    psk="<network_password>"
}
```

but still can't find wifi networks or change Wifi country in preferences.

Does anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

Comment: *The box has been working fine for years running wheezy* well, 2 years at most since that's how old that pi is - I find it amazing that two years ago you used wheezy, which is not supported on the 3B+ or even the 3B - in fact, not even jessie runs on the 3B+, stretch is the first version that supported the 3B+

Answer (score 1):

Configure the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as the link below because it has not configured in a true way and some part of it has lost:

[Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)

---

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` is like this and is working:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IR

network={
     ssid="testssid"
     psk="tesspass"
}
```

Now, if you check the interface list by `ifconfig` you would not see the `wlan0` on the list. So, you may found some solution that tells you to enable the `wlan0` by `ifconfig wlan0 up` but it doesn't work and would give `Operation not possible due to RF-kill` as the output.

---

By the following procedure, it will be solved:

```
iwconfig wlan0 txpower off

sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Now you can bring it up:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

---

Check the `wlan0` state by `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` or GUI on the top of the screen and you would see that it has worked.

---

***References:***

- [Setting WiFi up via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)
- [Setting up Wifi by Hand (Advanced)](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis)
- [pi wpa_supplicant](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=203716)
- [Operation not possible due to RF-kill](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146198)
- ['iwlist' -> interface doesn't support scanning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45338/iwlist-interface-doesnt-support-scanning-ubuntu-lts-10-04)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  When I type  `ifconfig wlan0 up` I get the message  `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`. So I continue and type  `iwconfig wlan0 txpower off` and get the message  `Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power (8B26) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted`

Comment: forgot to say, i edited my wpa_supplicant to look like yours except for country=GB

Comment: @M.Rostami Have in mind that the OP is still using Wheezy, e.g. rfkill isn't needed and maybe other things are different?

Comment: I'm using a fresh install of buster. Just tried those commands prefixed by sudo and got exactly the same error messages.

Comment: @user1106252 You should add this important information to your question. Please edit it.

Comment: it's in the first line of my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry to all for confusion, didn't read that carefully.

Comment: no probs :) mate

Comment: `Operation not permitted`, so run the commands by sudo at first on them. -- Are you sure the wireless card name is wlan0? Check it by `iwconfig`.

Comment: Ran `iwconfig` and got this output:  `eth0  no wireless extensions     lo   no wireless extensions`

Comment: It seems that it's a problem with the wireless card. Check [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=211383). Add `dtoverlay=pi3-enable-wifi` to `/boot/config.txt` and `reboot` the pi.

Comment: I took your point about it possibly being a wifi card problem so I fished out another b 1.1 that I had lying around and tried all the steps  you spelled out earlier on that. When i type `ifconfig` the wlan0 appears. The icon in the top-right of the screen show `eth0: Link is down` and `wlan0 is not associated`.

Comment: Well, associate the `wlan0` to your SSID by `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Hope it help you.

Comment: Also, just noted that each time I go into preferences that the Wifi country is no longer greyed out but eah time it says 'Country not set' ... I set it to GB but when I go back in it says not set...

Comment: Feel free to configure your device by the terminal. You may face a problem or error. Just search that and google will give some related results. Using the GUI for changing these configurations is not recommended.